# Listview hangs when I scroll in android

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, android-cursor

I am creating music player app and I used cursor to get songs from local storage. I successfully displayed songs along with album arts but when I scroll list it hangs. What should I do to solve this problem.

This is my cursor :

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION+">0", null, sortOrder);
```

Here is class which binds songs and album art with listview fields :

```
private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    String backgroundColor = "white";
    String someOtherBackgroundColor = "#F5F5F5";
    public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
        super(context, layout, c,
                new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID},
                new int[]{R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration,R.id.iv_art});
    }

    public Bitmap getAlbumart(Context context, Long album_id){
        Bitmap bm = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        try{
            final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            if (pfd != null){
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, options);
                pfd = null;
                fd = null;
            }
        } catch(Error ee){}
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


        if(cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 0)
        {
            view.setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
        }
        else
        {
            view.setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor(someOtherBackgroundColor));
        }


        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        ImageView iv_art = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_art);


        String a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));



        Long l = Long.parseLong(a);

        Bitmap art = getAlbumart(songlist.this,l);
        if(art!=null)
        {
            iv_art.setImageBitmap(art);
        }
        else
        {
            iv_art.setImageResource(R.mipmap.app_splash_screen_icon);
        }

        long durationInMs = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

        name.setText(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

        Utility d = new Utility();

        String durationInMin = d.convertDuration(durationInMs);

        duration.setText("" + durationInMin);

        view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

        bindView(v, context, cursor);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Here is the code which sets adapter of listview :

```
mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);

lv_songlist.setAdapter(mediaAdapter);
```

Comment: Your problem is in loading bitmap. Load bitmap in cache.

Comment: I don't know how to do this please give me the solution sir @Dheerubhai

Comment: Use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader or any other image loading library to load bitmap in imageviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you create a new row in your `ListView` you load the image from the storage on the UI-Thread. As loading data (especially images) from the storage is an operation that can take a little while it will block the UI-Thread from performing any work other than loading that image for a little while. This results in the "hanging" you experience.

Best solution would be to offload the image loading onto a different Thread. You can do this either manually or using one of the wildly used Image Loading Libraries out there (Picasso, Glide, UniversalImageLoader) which can do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Mauin and please provide me the solution if you have.

Comment: Thanks @Mauin. I will try this.

Comment: This link is not available @Mauin.

Comment: Failed formatting the link in the previous comment: https://square.github.io/picasso/